# Maintaining pulse, changing measure length

Tags: time-signatures, tempo

*TLDR; So I've got a piece that's predominantly in a nice, slow, 4/4 common time  at 76 bpm. Halfway through however, in order for the score to not look like a horrific mess, I needed to keep the same pulse (76 bpm), but instead count it in two, effectively halving the bar length and giving it a cut-common feel - the tempo/pulse stays the same, but the "conductor" is conducting in 2, not 4.*

I knew I didn't want to just write a tempo change 2x the previous one. I've never had to deal with up until now, but the solution I came up with was:

- Change from 4/4 (C) to cut-common.
- Specify "double time" in the new section
  However, I wasn't 100% sure if "double time" actually "doubled" the tempo or it just cancelled out the cut-common effect.

Tell me if my solution works and if not, any help on how to do this in a sleek way would be much appreciated.

tyty

Comment: Sounds as if it's actually *not* twice as fast - new crotchet = old  crotchet in duration. It's only the *feel* that's changed. You may have halved the length of the bar, but b.p.m. remains.

Comment: What's wrong with a tempo change 2x the previous one? "Doppio movimento" is a reasonably common tempo indication and means precisely that: double the previous tempo.

Comment: Please provide an example of the change in time section so that we can make a more informed opinion

Comment: @Dekkadeci - nothing wrong - in some pieces,  except here, crotchet = crotchet, so there's no doubling of tempo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd favour 2/4 and keeping crotchet/quarter=76 for two reasons. One is that changing the duration notation forces performers to re-adjust to the new notation; if you keep the same notated tempo, no re-adjustment is needed. Another reason: you say that you want to keep the same 76 BPM pulse (rather than a 152 BPM pulse). So if the music feels as if the pulse is the same, it seems more natural to notate it that way, too.

I don't know if this example is relevant to your piece but, just in case: the duet (no. 9) from Act 1 of Gilbert and Sullivan's The Sorcerer. The outer sections are  a gavotte, 4 moderately slow beats to the bar. Later sections are more impassioned with semiquavers/16ths. For those, the time sig changes to 2/4 but the pulse is the same.

Comment: I agree completely with this. Even if it would mean rewriting already written music from `2/2` to `2/4`, it just makes sense, totally no confusion.

Comment: The OP says this: "Halfway through however, in order for the score to not look like a horrific mess...". It's possible your answer will **never** get accepted as a result, as the question asker has already determined that the note lengths in the 2/4 version are too horrific to bear.

Comment: @Dekkadeci an example would greatly help, it maybe the exact opposite that the music before the change may need to be doubled in duration to suffice less "horrific mess".